# Fork Rails tasks into background job with job control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I've already written a class that runs a background job server by monitoring a table for submitted jobs.  The code required to run the server is essentially:

```
j = JobServer.new
j.run!
```

I've wrapped this in a Rake task for testing, but now I want a way to background the job and provide an init script to manage this server.  I've spent a while playing with the `daemons` gem, but finally came to the conclusion that it closes my file descriptors when spinning off a background proc.  This won't work since my database backend is SQLite3, and closing that file descriptor tends to make Rails angry.

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I'll add that I just saw the delayed_job gem in another user's answer, but I don't want to re-write my JobServer class if I can help it.

Comment: I think you should try resque or delayed_job,might be it's not too much change in your code.try resque as per my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you use the Spawn method

```
   http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn
```

Probably write a nice little rake that that will let you start/stop/restart your job server.

Comment: I ended up writing the logic myself with `Process::fork`.  I started looking at `Process::spawn` but I needed the Rails environment forked off from Rake.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.